# Auto populate upcoming (30 days or less) and expired due dates to a new tab from master due dates sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on an excel file that has a master list of upcoming due dates for calibrations that we must complete for our tools. I have already input a conditional statement to turn the expired tools red and the upcoming calibrations (30 days or less) yellow based off their next calibration dates. Is there a way to use macros to auto populate a new tab titled "upcoming calibration" with the rows highlighted in yellow and auto populate a "needs calibration" tab with the expired calibrations highlighted in red?  Any help would be greatly appreciated and feel free to ask questions if anything is unclear. Thank you.

Comment: Could you give a [MCVE] please ?

Answer (score 0):

[Excel Table Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG4mQ.png)

I am trying to send the expired calibrations (Next Calibration highlighted in red) to a new sheet (sheet 2) and the upcoming calibrations (Next calibration highlighted in yellow) to a separate sheet (sheet 3). Is there a way to do this through macros?

Comment: when I say send I mean the entire row associated with that expired or upcoming calibration.